# Проверить на сайте подписан ли юзер на страницу

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Есть цель:
При переходе на сайт с помощью JS надо проверить - подписан ли человек на паблик в вк или фейсбук.

Знаю что можно проверить вот таким вот методом API VK:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/groups.isMember?group_id=94697290&architect_code&user_id=299097873
```

Но возникает вопрос: как получить ID пользователя, не используя какое-то свое приложения для авторизации юзера на сайте?

Ибо это не должно требавать от пользователя каких-либо действий.

Зашел на сайт, не подписан - показало окошко "Подписаться"
Зашел на сайт, подписан - просто дальше работаешь с сайтом.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но нет. Там нет конкретного ответа. Есть ответ по поводу невидимой авторизации. Но там все равно необходимо пользователю авторизироваться через приложение вк. А мне нужно просто чтобы не заходя в вк и приложения от вк получить. id пользователя.

Comment: Там есть конкретный ответ, **никак**.

Comment: Все таки я еще подожду. Мб у кого-то есть пдобное решение

Comment: Если оно есть, то это уязвимость и должно быть (и, возможно будет) починено .-.